# How implement signal handler for two alarms at different times?

Tags: c, unix

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>


int first_alarm = 10;
int second_alarm = 40;

void first_handler(int sig){

  // do something

}

void second_handler(int sig){

   // do something

}


int main(){


  alarm(first_alarm);
  alarm(second_alarm);
  signal(SIGALRM, first_handler);
  signal(SIGALRM, second_handler);

}
```

How can i handle a situation like that?
I have to catch two alarms, at two different times, with two different handlers for doing different things.
It's possible to implement this with a sigaction struct?

Comment: You can't. If you want to use `alarm` then you have to set the second alarm when the first one fires so there's only one at a time.

Comment: What platform(s) are you targeting? Does your application have threads or an event loop? I think your question really is "how can I set up multiple timers" and in C the answer to that usually depends on the environment. For example in Linux, [timer fd's](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html) can work well. Or [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html) timers. Threads work less well but can be used.

Comment: No, i don’t have threads.I need two signal(alarm)for trigger two specific action during the esecution of my program.

Comment: As already pointed out, at any one time, you can have but one signal handler set for a specific signal.  What you are seeking to do cannot be done directly.  You might set a single handler which knows which of the two handlers should be called at the moment.  Or you can look into interval timers, or …

Comment: Note that the second call to `alarm()` cancels the remaining time until the first alarm would have gone off — and reports that time as the result.  In context, that means you have just one alarm signal scheduled. You must wait for the first to go off, then schedule the second for the difference between the first and the second. After the signal is detected, you have to set the alarm again. In general, your application will need to keep a list of alarm times (delta from previous time is easiest), and schedule the handling appropriately (which is the current event; which function handles it?).

Comment: Read carefully [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html). Don't use `alarm` but timers, e.g. [timer_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html) etc...